# how to add a device for the project that based on cocos2d-box2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I create a project based on cocos2d-box2d, when I want to debug it on a device, but it can not get the device, so what should i do?please look the picture here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9g2a.png

but if I create a project just based on cocos2d, the device can show in the list, so what should I do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to setup your device for development. In Xcode, choose Window -> Organizer and from there devices. You can then enable development for a connected device. After that it should show up instead of the generic "iOS Device".

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks for your reply, and I have done that, but it still can not show up.thanks

Comment: Your iPod touch is also running iOS 5, right? If not, you will have to change the deployment target (under build settings) of your project to the iOS version that's installed on your iPod touch.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks for your reply,and my iPod touch is running iOS 4.3, and i have change the deployment target of project to 4.3, but it still doesn't show, so sad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very vague... You never stated what device you are trying to make an app for, so I'm going to presume you want an Iphone app. Just select [Iphone 5.0 simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9g2a.png)

And I cannot answer your second question, because I'm not too sure of what you are asking.

Comment: thanks for your reply, and I debug this project by using iPod touch, I want to debug it on iPod touch, and i do not want to debug it on the simulator, by the way, the project is a universal project,thanks